# google custom search api return is different from google.com

Tags: python, google-custom-search

I am using google api via python and it works, but the result I got from api is totally different from google.com. I found the top result given by custom search are google calendar,google earth and patents. I wonder if there is a way to get same result from custom search api. Thank you

```
def googleAPICall(self,userInput):  
        try:  
            userInput = urllib.quote(userInput)        
            for i in range(0,1):
                index = i*10+1 
                url = ('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?'    
                       'key=%s'
                       '&cx=%s'
                       '&alt=json'
                       '&num=10'
                       '&start=%d'
                       '&q=%s')%(self.KEY,self.CX,index,userInput)   
                print (url)

                request = urllib2.Request(url)
                response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            returnResults = simplejson.load(response)
            webs = returnResults['items'] 

            for web in webs:
                self.result.append(web["link"])
    except:
        print ("search error")
        self.result.append("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_change")

    return self.result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a 'search outside of google'checkbox in the dashboard. you will get the same result after you check it. it takes me a while to find it out. the default sitting is only return search result inside of all google websites.

Answer (score 0):

After some searches, the answer is "It is impossible to have the same result as google.com".

Google clearly stated it:
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/141877?hl=en

Hope that this is the definite answer.

Comment: Do you know any alternative with real-time search result?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to galaxyan answer, you can still do that by changing `Sites to search` from `Search only included sites` to `Search the entire web`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to experiment with four parameters cr, gl, hl, lr

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).